# Issues with neo4j.rb, JRuby. Cannot start rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, neo4j, ruby-on-rails-4.2, jrubyonrails

I am trying to create an application with JRuby, Rails and Neo4j.
I tried installing neo4j and get it started with Rails 5.0.0, but I got several complaint regarding a missing (???)  activesupport gem. Which is weird because the gem is listed when I run  “gem list”. Well, I tried doing the same using Rails 4.2.6. After many temporary tweaks to eliminate some issues reported below, I finally got neo4j to start. However, I could not start the Rails server unless I commented out almost every line in confit/initializers/new_framework_defaults.rb. Here are the reported errors, and how I dealt with them. Is there a better solution for this, that will not imply enabling/disabling all this configuration methods?

Could please anyone suggest methods to go around/solve all these issues?

1. gem install rails -v 4.2
2. bundle exec rails new myApp -m http://neo4jrb.io/neo4j/neo4j.rb -O
3. cd myApp && bundle exec rake neo4j:install[community-latest]

   - I had to disable "require "action_cable/engine"" in config/application.rb
4. START NEO4j: bundle exec rake neo4j:start

   > PROBLEM 1: NameError: uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::EventedFileUpdateChecker

   - I disabled the line *config.file_watcher = ActiveSupport::EventedFileUpdateChecker*
      in config/environments/development.rb. Then re-ran bundle exec rake neo4j:start.

   > PROBLEM 2: NoMethodError: undefined method `to_time_preserves_timezone=' for ActiveSupport:Module.

   - I commented out the line *ActiveSupport.to_time_preserves_timezone = true*
      in config/initializers/new_framework_defaults.rb:15. Then re-ran bundle exec rake neo4j:start.

   > PROBLEM 3: NoMethodError: undefined method 'halt_callback_chains_on_return_false=' for ActiveSupport:Module

   - I commented out the line *ActiveSupport.halt_callback_chains_on_return_false = false*
      in config/initializers/new_framework_defaults.rb. Then re-ran bundle exec rake neo4j:start.

   > PROBLEM 4: NoMethodError: undefined method `perform_caching=' for ActionMailer::Base:Class

   - I then commented out the line *config.action_mailer.perform_caching*
      in config/application.rb: require "action_mailer/railtie"
   - I also commented out the following lines in config/environments/development
         *config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false*
         *config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false*

Then re-ran bundle exec rake neo4j:start:

FINALLY, IT WORKED

5) Starting be rails s

> PROBLEM: "Rack app error: #< RuntimeError: Invalid option key: per_form_csrf_tokens=>"

I set *Rails.application.config.action_controller.per_form_csrf_tokens = false*
 in config/initializers/new_framework_defaults.rb. However, it did not help.
Below is the full error message:

I had to comment out the line *Rails.application.config.action_controller.forgery_protection_origin_check = true* in config/initializers/new_framework_defaults.rb

- Version 3.4.0 (jruby 9.0.4.0 - ruby 2.2.2), codename: Owl Bowl Brawl
- Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
- Environment: development
- Listening on tcp://localhost:3000
  Use Ctrl-C to stop
  2016-07-05 17:24:39 -0600: Rack app error: #
  /Users/yandj/.gem/jruby/2.2.2/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_controller/railtie.rb:59:in `block in Railtie'
  org/jruby/RubyHash.java:1343:in`each'
  /Users/yandj/.gem/jruby/2.2.2/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_controller/railtie.rb:54:in `block in Railtie'
  org/jruby/RubyBasicObject.java:1633:in`instance_eval'
  /Users/yandj/.gem/jruby/2.2.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `execute_hook'
  /Users/yandj/.gem/jruby/2.2.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:45:in`block in run_load_hooks'
  org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1560:in `each'
  /Users/yandj/.gem/jruby/2.2.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in`run_load_hooks'
  /Users/yandj/.gem/jruby/2.2.2/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_controller/base.rb:266:in `<class:Base>'
  /Users/yandj/.gem/jruby/2.2.2/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_controller/base.rb:164:in`'
  /Users/yandj/.gem/jruby/2.2.2/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_controller/base.rb:5:in `<top>'
  /Users/yandj/.gem/jruby/2.2.2/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:1:in`(root)'
  /Users/yandj/.gem/jruby/2.2.2/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:69:in `ext'
  /Users/yandj/.gem/jruby/2.2.2/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:27:in`match?'
  /Users/yandj/.gem/jruby/2.2.2/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:114:in `call'
  /Users/yandj/.gem/jruby/2.2.2/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in`call'
  /Users/yandj/.gem/jruby/2.2.2/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
  /Users/yandj/.gem/jruby/2.2.2/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/application.rb:165:in`call'
  /Users/yandj/.gem/jruby/2.2.2/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
  /Users/yandj/.gem/jruby/2.2.2/gems/puma-3.4.0-java/lib/puma/configuration.rb:224:in`call'
  /Users/yandj/.gem/jruby/2.2.2/gems/puma-3.4.0-java/lib/puma/server.rb:569:in `handle_request'
  /Users/yandj/.gem/jruby/2.2.2/gems/puma-3.4.0-java/lib/puma/server.rb:406:in`block in process_client'
  org/jruby/RubyProc.java:318:in `call'

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I think we should have a note in our `README` about this.  Could you try the `rails5` branch?

```
gem 'neo4j', github: 'neo4jrb/neo4j', branch: 'rails5'
```

Comment: Hi Brian,Thanks for responding.
I tried your suggestion. Still not working</br>
  Repository not found.
Retrying git clone 'git://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4j.git.git' "/Users/yandj/.gem/jruby/2.2.2/cache/bundler/git/neo4j.git-c1a4e5d18f00aafb133aa5a89b740980e92b9867" --bare --no-hardlinks --quiet due to error (2/4): Bundler::Source::Git::GitCommandError Git error: command `git clone 'git://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4j.git.git' "/Users/yandj/.gem/jruby/2.2.2/cache/bundler/git/neo4j.git-c1a4e5d18f00aafb133aa5a89b740980e92b9867" --bare --no-hardlinks --quiet` in directory

Comment: Oh, sorry, the `.git` shouldn't be there.  Just changed the answer to fix this.

Also since Rails 5 is officially out now we're working now on getting this branch into a 7.1.0 release of the gem

Comment: I used this: gem 'neo4j', '~> 7.0.5', branch: 'rails5'. no change

Comment: Could you try taking away the version specification and adding the `github` option?  The branch actually specifies versions 7.0.3 (because that's when it was made), so just try copy/pasting what's in the answer